# Using array.push not giving correctly structured array (cant use array with filter function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm using array.push to push the contents of a JSON response to an array. But when doing it, it adds some weird formating to my array. As a result, I cannot use the filter function to filter the array. I hard coded some json in another test case, and successfully used the filter function (see images below of comparisons of console.logs)

**The JSON response looks like this:**

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1702574719019,
      "title": "Title 1",
      "published_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:36-05:00",
      "created_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:37-05:00",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:38-05:00",
      "vendor": "DZR"
    },
    {
      "id": 1702574719019,
      "title": "Title 2",
      "published_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:36-05:00",
      "created_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:37-05:00",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-16T09:40:38-05:00",
      "vendor": "DZR"
    }
  ]
}
```

**How I handle this data looks like this (snippet from success ajax callback):**

```js
    var this.postList = [];
    var t = this;
      while (i < pages) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "" + i,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          success: function(data) {

            $.each( data.posts, function( i, value ) {
              t.postList.push( value );
            });

          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
          }
        });
        i++;
      }
```

**This is how postList looks when I console.log it. The objects are not inside the Array [], like the image after this.**
[image]

**This is how I presume it should look, thus not letting me use array.filter correctly (returns nothing)**
[image]

I believe I am using array.push incorrectly, and not correctly adding the objects to the array and therefore it looking weird when I console.log it. But I have no idea how to correct this, any info would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please create a demo?

Comment: @brk Not without exposing the API I'm using. But that is literally the majority of the code I am using, rest is the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword you are using refers to the scope you're currently in. Thus, `this` refers to the callback called on `$.each`.

In order to push your values to `postList`, just use the following:

```
postList.push(...)
```

instead of

```
this.postList.push(...)
```

Comment: I didnt post the full snippet. But It should actually be t.postList. I have declared t to = this at the start of the class.I can add the data fine, its the structure that is messed up.

Comment: So your code does push it to postList, but the output is not as expected? If so, what is the desired output? Because the screen you are providing looks completely normal.

Comment: Look at the images I posted, the second one has the array objects inside the array. I'm trying to use the filter function to filter the array. But its not working cause my array is clearly not valid. Even if I do array.length on it, it doesnt give the length.

Comment: Could you post the full code then? With the request and the console log. It could be the problem that the request made is asynchronous, meaning that the output is logged before the full JSON array was pushed.

Comment: Updated Original Post

Comment: Added async: false, and now I can properly use the filter function! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this in a callback.

You can do this by just

```
postList = data.posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$.each( data.posts, function( i, value ) {
    postList.push( value );
});
```

without this. It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
this.postList = [];
var t = this;
success: function(data) {
  $.each( data.posts, function( i, value ) {
    t.postList.push( value );
  });
}
```

Here just define this.postList as array and then use it to push values.